# Bind dynamic properties using JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I have a edit screen which displays a series of editable properties(fields) of an entity. And this list of fields are dynamic,in the sense that any field can be added/removed from the list without any code change. I have a model something like this.

```
public class Property{

 private String displayName;
 private String value;
 private int displayOrder;
 //other props,getters,setters etc..
}
```

My backingBean has a map of these properties (for some other reasons,we chose map as the datastructure).

```
public class BackingBean{

private Map<String,Property> editableProps;
//other props,getters,setters etc..
}
```

The problem is with iterating over this map and produce a textbox for each of the entry. Since a4j:repeat(richfaces) doesn't iterate over a map,I have decided to use JSTL and the code fragment looks something like this,

```
<c:forEach items="${mybean.editableProps}"
                var="item" >
    <tr>
     <td>
      <c:out value="${item.value.displayName}"/>
     </td>
     <td>
      <input type="text" value="${item.value.value}" />
     </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

This will work fine except for the fact that the binding of a ui field to bean's property will not happen automatically. If I try using **h:inputText** inside **c:forEach**, the component doesn't get rendered.(Guess the jstl var is not available for the jsf).
**Is there a JSF way of doing all this(Using *hashmap*)**?So that a textbox is produced for each entry in the map and any change to it gets bound the underlying java bean property.?

Comment: 9 months later and I am having the EXACT same issue.  Did you ever solve it?

Comment: No, just implemented it in a non-jsf way.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed code woudl work in current versions of JSF.
But also, an easier way to achieve this nowadays is to make your bean a map itself.

```java
@Component("prop")
public class PropertyBean extends HashMap<String, Property>{
    public PropertyBean() {
        this.put("prop1", property1);
        this.put("prop2", property2);
    }
}
```

And in the facelets

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{prop.prop1.displayName}" />
<h:outputText value="#{prop.prop1.value}" />
```